# Is saving disk space still considered to be an advantage of Normalization?

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

I have read a while back that one of the advantages of Normalization is to save disk space (since Normalization minimizes redundancy), but is saving disk space still considered to be an advantage of Normalization in current time where disk storage is very cheap?

Comment: Since databases like to keep the working set in memory ("buffer cache"), any space saving arguments probably equally apply to RAM usage.

Comment: You have already posted this question in [Database Administrator site](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228645/is-saving-disk-space-still-considered-to-be-an-advantage-of-normalization). Please do not cross-post the same question in different sites of StackExchange. On that site you have got two comprehensive comments. If you are not satisfied, please explain in more details what are you really asking, and why are you asking this (in only one site, removing the post from the other one).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228645/is-saving-disk-space-still-considered-to-be-an-advantage-of-normalization

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the resource impact from normalizing a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379340/what-is-the-resource-impact-from-normalizing-a-database)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is an advantage. Sometimes disk space is not an issue, sometimes it is. For example, when you have large amounts of data, or the storage is expensive, or a capacity planing mistake has been made.

Saving space is also helpful to get more out of your RAM for caching purposes.

It entirely depends on the concrete case whether it is worth trying to save space.